# Get Background Image from View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift

i need to access the background image in on of my segues. To access the UIImage i started to build a protocol/extension…

**The Problem (of course):**

'UIViewController' does not have a member named 'backgroundImage'

How do I fix this?

```
protocol InsetBlurModalSequeProtocol {
    func getBackgroundImage() -> UIImage
}

extension UIViewController: InsetBlurModalSequeProtocol {
    func getBackgroundImage() -> UIImage {
        return self.backgroundImage.image
    }
}
```

Comment: Or is there a way to cast an "Anyobject" to a ViewController and a Protocol?

Comment: Do you want to extend your own view controller class instead?

Comment: Yeah, kind of. I need to access the backgroundImage.image in a segue. So maybe I just go for a strong type? Wait, strong type ist not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from whichever UIViewController u want the background image in the resultant one.
Store that background image in a UIImage first(set this UIImage property in the .h file first).
Import that viewController.h in your desired view controller, or as i can see you have called a method via delegate(that will do too) call that image and use an instant UIImage .
Set the background image of the resultant view controller u want in viewDidLoad method

```
   self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternColor:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.extension"]]; //or give the UIImage filename.
```